# How Can I add links at the side to the WordPress website which shows me the current section?

Tags: html, wordpress, elementor

Actually, I am making a long page. I want to give users the ability they can have a track which section he is in. And I am using the Elementor page builder. Does Elementor provide this functionality? Please let me know your answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Elementor has a Table of Contents widget which will generate a ToC based on the heading tags (h1, h2, h3, etc.) used on the page. If you were to put that widget on the side of the page and made it stick throughout, your user will get see the heading become a different colour in the ToC when he is at that section.

Here are some Elementor resources on the Table of Contents:
https://elementor.com/blog/table-of-contents/
https://elementor.com/blog/introducing-table-of-contents/
https://elementor.com/widgets/table-of-contents-widget/

Comment: Thanks, Daan, It really works. Again thank you very much. Can you please tell me how can I handle it on mobile? I made a sidebar. But it is doing the problem with a mobile version. If I keep visible on mobile. Other content is not visible. Can I do if the page scroll sidebar hides and when the static sidebar show. Is it possible in elementor. I will very grateful. Thanks in advance